# Sprite Effect Challenge, Shadow Distortion [libgdx]

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I have a sprite that represents a shadow.

My game uses a top down view. The point is that the player in some moments fleet and passes over other objects (sprites) and I need the shadow is distorted as it passes by vertical walls. For example:

[image: shadow distortion image]

I've considered several strategies to accomplish this, but none convince me at all. For example:

[image: strategy image]

- make the shadow is drawn under the wall (1)
- and make a "magical" algorithm appears above another (2).

But the frontal and lateral distortion are very different :/

Any contribution or ideas will help me, thanks. (sorry for my English)

Comment: Do you think your question might be understood by anyone? A picture for explaining your actual problem would be great. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13497625/dafuq.png

Comment: jeje sorry.I'm new here, and I can not post images. Thanks for the edition. :D